# Can anyone help with solving these questions on vectors?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Given the vectors:
a =(−7,3,−10),b =(2,1,5), and c =(18,4,m), with m being a real number.

e) Use the determinant det (a,b,c) to determine m so that the three vectors are linear
dependent.

f) Calculate for the m value from the previous part the coefficients α and β in the linear
combination: c = αa + βb.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: for e) I've tried putting the vectors into a matrix to get the determinant. For f) I don't actually know where to start

Answer (score 0):

e) The vectors are linearly dependent if the determinant ($510-13m$) is zero.  Solve that.

f) Plug in your $m$ and solve for your $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: So just work out 510-13m=0 and solve for m?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!